# Disadvantages of running Tomcat on Port 80

Tags: tomcat7

This could be very basic question. I was wondering what could be disadvantages of running Tomcat server on port 80 for a J2EE App. Will there be any slowness/performance issues while serving static content?

I know for sure, few application servers definately have problems loading the UI if made to run on port 80 and hence it requires a IIS connector.

But as Tomcat can server as both Application and Web server, is it a good idea to make it listen directly on port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI..  We use Apache Tomcat 6 via port 80.  However, it is a "back-of-the-house" application that does not traverse the DMZ and connects to the front-end app using SOAP calls.

I did support another app that used an ISAPI re-direct which worked..  It was just a bit odd as you had to go through IIS to get to Apache.

Depending your version of JDK, you should be fine.  I did read about some issues with JDK 1.6 u 22 or thereabouts on the Atlassian website.

I know you are running Tomcat7, and our new version of the app we support runs under Tomcat7, but not under VMWare..  We have to run Tomcat 6.  Tomcat 6.0.36 does not stop services cleanly for us..  Tomcat 6.0.35 works pretty well.